# How can I extract the pname of an Android APK in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, xml, apk, android-manifest

We're dealing with a project where we have to calculate an MD5 and extract the pname of an APK that's being uploaded in a form. We've done the MD5 bit already but are now stumped at the pname one.

The pname is contained inside AndroidManifest.xml, so we could use a JS zip library to extract AndroidManifest.xml from the APK, but then the problem is it's in binary XML. On the server side, we'd just use aapt or apktool to unpack and decode the APK, then read AndroidManifest.xml in plaintext, but what do we do in JS?

Binary AndroidManifest.xml looks something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWBi0.png.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After finding out the name for the binary XML Android uses is AXML, and finding references to AXMLPrinter, the best we came up with so far is extracting the AndroidManifest.xml file with the JS zip library, sending it to the server, then using either [AXMLPrinter2.jar](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/android4me/AXMLPrinter2.jar):

`java -jar AXMLPrinter2.jar AndroidManifest.xml`

or [the Python port](https://github.com/tracer0tong/axmlprinter):

`python axmlprinter.py  -i AndroidManifest.xml`

I'd still love to find the JS implementation of AXMLPrinter, but I suppose this will do otherwise.